# Shorten branch names in terminal with powerlevel9k and zsh

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh, powerline

I am currently using powerlevel9k in zsh. It shows me my current directory, the current VCS branch I'm on (git in this case). While I can limit the number of directories shown (i.e. show no more than 2 directories), I don't know how to limit the git branch name to be shown.

If I have a branch name called `this-is-a-really-long-branch-name-for-no-good-reason`, then it takes over my terminal and the lines wrap. This is specifically annoying when working in multiple panes. I would like to suppress it after say 30 characters. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already a Pull Request for this. Have a look at [#798](https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k/pull/798). It will arrive at the `next` branch shortly. It would be awesome, if you could try it out, and document your findings in the Pull Request.
You can find the documentation for that [here](https://github.com/floor114/powerlevel9k/blob/111d152d48cc92229cb523a992a0ecee740381e7/README.md#vcs-symbols) (after the Symbols description).